# How to add spaces between bar code lines - iTextSharp

Tags: c#, image, itext, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am creating bar code in memory and displaying it on the web, there are two issues with it; 1) bar code length is small (2nd image) and text quality is not great (2nd image) .

I am trying to get the result shown in the first image where bar code length and text quality is great.

Is there any way to increase the bar code length or width ? and improve the text quality ?

iTextSharp version: 5.5.13.1

[image]

**Here is the code**

```
// create a blank image
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpimg;

bmpimg = GenerateBarCodeImage65(barCode);
context.Response.Write("<img src='data:image/bmp;base64," + ImageToBase64(bmpimg, ImageFormat.Bmp) + "'  />");
context.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");

context.Response.End();
bmpimg.Dispose();
barCodeImg.Dispose();

private System.Drawing.Bitmap GenerateBarCodeImage65(string barcode)
{
  System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpimg = new Bitmap(236, 88);
  Graphics graphics = graphics.FromImage(bmpimg);

    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 236, 88));
    // generate the Code128 barcode
    graphics.DrawImage(CreateBarcode(barcode, 65), 5, 5);
    // generate the text below the barcode image.
    graphics.DrawString(barcode, new Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(5, 68));


  graphics.Dispose();

  return bmpimg;
}



 private System.Drawing.Image CreateBarcode(string barcodeLen, Int32 height)
   {
    Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
    code128.CodeType = iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CODE128;
    code128.ChecksumText = true;
    code128.GenerateChecksum = true;
    code128.BarHeight = height;
    code128.Code = barcodeLen;
    barCodeImg = code128.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);
    return barCodeImg;
   }


 private string ImageToBase64(Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bar code symbols are fonts.  So you need to change the font size or font.

Comment: Not sure why you bothered clearing the text below when anyone can just scan that barcode anyway. The information is still there...